# ESPHOME not working for MHz19 with Lolin D1 mini

Tags: home-assistant, esphome

I connected the MHz19 sensor to the D1 mini and want to flash it via ESP-Home.

I followed the following guide:
https://esphome.io/components/sensor/mhz19.html

I used the code

```
esphome:
  name: co2-sensor

esp8266:
  board: esp01_1m

# Enable logging
#logger:

  
# Enable Home Assistant API
api:

ota:
  password: "xxxxxx"

wifi:
  ssid: !secret wifi_ssid
  password: !secret wifi_password

  # Enable fallback hotspot (captive portal) in case wifi connection fails
  ap:
    ssid: "Co2-Sensor Fallback Hotspot"
    password: "xxxxx"

captive_portal:


uart:
  rx_pin: GPIO3
  tx_pin: GPIO1
  baud_rate: 9600

sensor:
  - platform: mhz19
    co2:
      name: "CO2 Value"
    temperature:
      name: "MH-Z19 Temperature"
    update_interval: 60s
    automatic_baseline_calibration: false
```

But cannot flash, I get the following error

```
======================== [SUCCESS] Took 305.85 seconds ========================
INFO Successfully compiled program.
esptool.py v3.2
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting......................................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://github.com/espressif/esptool#troubleshooting
INFO Upload with baud rate 460800 failed. Trying again with baud rate 115200.
esptool.py v3.2
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting......................................

A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://github.com/espressif/esptool#troubleshooting
```

I can however flash it and it comes online if I disconnect the sensor, of course it publishes no data. So I assume it's something to do with UART. I also tried disabling the logging, which did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the UART pins used by default for debug logging, even though I thought I had disabled the logging option. I used pin 4 and 5 and it worked.

https://esphome.io/components/uart.html#uart

Note that the value I got was 5000 ppm at first, when it was plugged into the Pi on which I'm running HA. When connecting to another PSU I got 'normal' looking values. I assume it simply did not get enough power from the PI.